# Canon LBP 6230DW won't print under Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: drivers, wireless, printing, canon

I tried adding my Canon printer via wireless connenction to my laptop. I used this driver provided by canon: https://www.canon-europe.com/support/consumer_products/products/printers/laser/i-sensys_lbp6230dw.aspx?type=drivers&language=EN&os=Linux%20(64-bit)
If I install any newer version (I found v 3.40 instead of 1.40) it won't even recognize the printer, stating it's generic tex-only printer, and even worse, in this case the printing job immediately gets cancelled in the minute I press the print button.

Using the 1.40 driver, the printer has been added, and even softwares (LibreOffice, even emulated MS Office) see the the printer, but it's stuck at "processing" for some reason I don't quite understand. If I have look at the error message it shows: " **- src = bidiCommon.c, line = 349, err = 0¥nDEBUG2: prtMarkerSuppliesLevel.1.1 = 100**" More to that, I know that the ink level is not full (if the value indicates that), because it can't even print the user data page properly.

The system sees the printer, when I run lpinfo -v, I get these results:

- file cups-brf:/
- network lpd
- network http
- network beh
- network socket
- network ipps
- network ipp
- direct hp
- network https
- direct hpfax
- network bjnp
- List item

**network dnssd://Canon%20LBP6230dw._pdl-datastream._tcp.local/**

- **network socket://192.168.0.94**

I suspected something must be with the wireless connection, so I pinged the IP adress, the result I think shows, that something else is the problem, the result:

- PING 192.168.0.94 (192.168.0.94) 56(84) bytes of data.
- **7 packets transmitted, 7 received, 0% packet loss, time 6006ms rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 11.032/38.847/74.303/25.210 ms**

In theory the port are open, because nmap gets this result:

Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2018-02-09 11:42 CET
Nmap scan report for 192.168.0.94
Host is up (0.041s latency).
Not shown: 997 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
80/tcp   open  http
515/tcp  open  printer
**9100/tcp open  jetdirect**
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 17.60 seconds

I'm sorry for the formatting,it's my first post here, so I didn't quite figure out when causes Enter a new paragraph. I highlighted wit bold font the text, which I think might be the most relevant.

I appreciate any help coming. Thank you in advance:
David

Comment: Try this: https://radu.cotescu.com/how-to-install-canon-lbp-printers-in-ubuntu/.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Canon LBP6000 in Ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/174474/installing-canon-lbp6000-in-ubuntu-12-04)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I tried following the steps in the instructions, but I don't have the CAPT drivers for my printer, only UFRII LT drivers according to the Canon site. The script didn't work as it's  not one among the listed models, unfortunately.

Comment: I had similar problems with Xerox 3030 Phaser laser printer. The problem was solved by replacing part of the printing libraries with their i386 counterparts, as x64 drivers had some incompatibilities.

Comment: so Canon recommend the UFRII driver; http://support-asia.canon-asia.com/contents/ASIA/EN/0100595001.html at version 1.4 as you say; it was released 14th Nov 2017. There seem to be issues with 17.10 and the Canon UFR (version 3.4) and UFRII drivers; Canon updated them both Nov 2017; (presumably for 17.04) and I understood they were working on new drivers; one can only hope that 18.04; the LTS version will settle better; 17.10 has also had scanner issues; sadly it is the innovators who move ahead to new releases who discover these issues;

Comment: Thank you for the information! So I guess it's for the best if I wait for the LTS version and hope that Canon provides driver for Bionic. It seems Artful was released in a hurry due to the major changes that happened (GNOME, GDM etc.) and driver suppor suffers for it.

Answer (score 1):

It is suggested that one edit the ppd file; /etc/cups/ppd/[yourprinter].ppd

and add the line

> *CN_PDL_ConvertUserPaper: "dummy"

---

where it says [yourprinter]

this means find the ppd file relevant to your printer; in the folder ppd that is inside /etc/cups/

---

so if one uses the text editor gedit, the command would be

```
gksudo gedit /etc/cups/ppd/[yourprinter].ppd
```

.... but please do insert the correct name for your ppd file

I understand canon are working on a revision of the driver; note this is the 1.4 driver from here http://support-asia.canon-asia.com/contents/ASIA/EN/0100595001.html that comes down as linux-UFRIILT-drv-v140_uken.tar.gz so it is **UFRIILT-drv-v140**